# Embedding a TIF into a file

Tags: c#, embed, tiff

I'm writing a program that will need to embed a TIF in an XML document.  It needs to mimic the way our vendor does this.  It doesn't appear to be base64 encoded, as it begins with a HEX of 49 49 ("II"), which to me means that it's the actual image binary data.  I can't seem to find a way to embed the data in c# (Visual Studio) that mimics this format.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: As a note, the beginning part of the content is a tag that our software reads in - date, some data, 'F' for front image, 'BW' for Black and White.  The payload itself starts at "II" or "49 49".

Comment: As an additional note, I'm not using the XMLWriter because of some other headaches that come along with that.  The data is being written out just writing formatted lines to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my bad - it was an ANSI Windows-1252 character set, and I was able to write the byte[] directly in with .Write rather than .WriteLine.